# Exporting CLOB Json files

Tags: json, db2, clob, dbvisualizer

we would like to export various CLOB/Json data from the database in dbvisulizer as json-files.

```
@export on;

@export set filename="P:\FP_Data.json";

SELECT    R.data FROM schema.REQUESTtab R WHERE  r.id in '81652f6b8128';

@export off;
```

The data is spuriously exported, as no data is retrieved in the target file.

So far, we have manually downloaded the data from the DB and changed the format manually in Ultraedit, which is very time-consuming for various db records.

Are there any optional parameters in the export command line that are helpful in our use case, in order to retrieve the following format.

Can you please verify and let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider setting  more options (with `@export set`) e.g. `CLOBFormat="File"` , and `CLOBFileDir=...` , or  `Format="JSON"`.  Refer to the users guide for details.

Comment: Thanks @mao. The comment below I have added the latest update

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.

```
 @export on;

@export set filename="P:\FP_Data.json" CLOBFormat=VALUE   Format=JSON   JSONColumnHeaderIsColumnAlias =FALSE  JSONStyle = rows ;

SELECT    R.data FROM schema.REQUESTtab R WHERE  r.id in '81652f6b8128';

@export off;
```

The following format is required:

However, we obtain:

The "/" is automatically added and the overall format is not in line with the expected raw data.

Can you please verify?

Comment: If you cannot work it out from the information in the dbvis Users Guide, then search and open an item on the dbvis discussion forums. They've been quite helpful to me in the past.   https://support.dbvis.com/support/discussions